# Loop array of bytes only for ones

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array of bytes. Some are 0's and some are 1's.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

byte[] bytes = new byte[100];
```

I want to loop only for 1's. How to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by 1's?

Comment: loop over the array and use `if` condition for processing on `1`'s.

Comment: byte is not bit if that what you meant

Comment: i don't want to loop on all array because it has large size . i want to loop on items in the array that have value 1 and discard items that have 0 value

Comment: You can't. If you want to filter and array you have to at least go over the array once. This cannot be done less o(n).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A for loop with a test should do the trick.

```
    BitSet bs = new BitSet(100000000); 
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {bs.set(i);}
    long stDate = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int i = 0; (i = bs.nextSetBit(i + 1)) >= 0;) {// TODO}
    long endDate = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println(endDate - stDate);

    byte[] bytes = new byte[100000000];
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {bytes[i] = 1;}
    stDate = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (byte b : bytes) {  if (b == 1) // TODO}
    endDate = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println(endDate - stDate);
```

Comment: I suspect you are suffering from a lot of dead code elimination.  BTW `new Date().getTime()` is the same as `System.currentTimeMillis()`

Comment: Thank you for the correction, but it does not impact the result.

Answer (score 0):

> i don't want to loop on all array because it has large size . i

Actually 100 bytes is trivial. It uses 2 cache lines.  However if you wanted to improve performance you would use a bit set which only use one bit per 0 or 1 instead of 8.

```
BitSet bs = new BitSet(1 << 20); // 1 Mb
for(int i = 0; (i = bs.nextSetBit(i+1)) >= 0;)
    System.out.println("Next set bit is " + i);
```

This still has to loop through the data but it can examine 64-bits at once.

Comment: if array is very large can i reduce time to looping it?

Comment: thank you peter . i actually  doesn't mean 100 item , i have about 100000000 item sometimes .Is the code of BitSet will reduce time as much as possible

Comment: @andolsizied while the test is flawed, you might be right depending on the situation. +1